# React typescript MUI Autocomplete Type 'Product[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly never[][]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have below ReactJS use hook from Autocomplete field, using Typescript version `4.9.5`.

VS code editor giving error in `options={products}` line. looking some help to fix this error message.

code URL:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bhabha-uhti49?file=/src/CarAutoComplete.tsx:1697-1718

```
<Controller
          control={methods.control}
          name={"selectedProducts"}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              multiple
              id="product-selection"
              options={products}
              getOptionLabel={(product) => product.name}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="standard"
                  label="Select a Product"
                  placeholder="Type to filter list"
                />
              )}
              onChange={(_, data) => {
                onChange(data);
                return data;
              }}
              defaultValue={initFormFieldValues.selectedProducts}
            />
          )}
        />
```

**Error message**

> (property) UseAutocompleteProps<never[], true, false, false>.options:
> readonly never[][] Array of options.

> Type 'Product[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly never[][]'.
> Type 'Product' is missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, > > push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)

**full code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Select, MenuItem, Autocomplete } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface FormFields {
  invoiceNumber: number;
  selectedProducts: Array<Product>;
}

export default function CarAutoComplete() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<Product>>([
    { id: 1, name: "Mouse" },
    { id: 2, name: "Printer" },
    { id: 3, name: "Monitor" },
    { id: 4, name: "server" }
  ]);

  const initFormFieldValues = {
    invoiceNumber: 0,
    selectedProducts: []
  };

  const methods = useForm<FormFields>({
    defaultValues: initFormFieldValues
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: FormFields) => alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "400px", margin: "20px" }}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={methods.control}
          name={"invoiceNumber"}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <TextField
              variant="standard"
              style={{ margin: "5px" }}
              onChange={onChange}
              value={value}
              placeholder="Invoice Number"
              type="number"
            />
          )}
        />
        <br />

        <Controller
          control={methods.control}
          name={"selectedProducts"}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              multiple
              id="product-selection"
              options={products}
              getOptionLabel={(product) => product.name}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="standard"
                  label="Select a Product"
                  placeholder="Type to filter list"
                />
              )}
              onChange={(_, data) => {
                onChange(data);
                return data;
              }}
              defaultValue={initFormFieldValues.selectedProducts}
            />
          )}
        />

        <Button variant="contained" style={{ margin: "5px" }} type="submit">
          Send
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change needed is to specify the type (`FormFields`) of `initFormFieldValues`. Without this, TypeScript infers an undesirable type for `initFormFieldValues.selectedProducts` and then it thinks that the type of what you provide for the `options` prop conflicts (with regard to `Autocomplete`'s expectations about how they should relate) with the type of what you provide for the `defaultValue` prop.

```
  const initFormFieldValues: FormFields = {
    invoiceNumber: 0,
    selectedProducts: []
  };
```

[image: Edit TypeScript error]